# How can I ignore certain expressions from being compared using Difflib library

Tags: python, parsing, ignore, difflib

I want to create logic which will interact with the `Difflib.ndiff()` function that can compare text. Currently I want it to check text reports which show data from the test files. My problem stems from the Timestamps within the report

```
Text1 =
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss Report content shjsjsjsjdj
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss more Report to check content shjsjsjsjdj
```

Text2
`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` same Report content to `text1` `shjsjsjsjdj`
`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` more different Report to check content `shjsjsjsjdj`

Most lines will contain the time stamp. How can I make it so the `ndiff()` ignored when checking timestamps??

```
Tags returned by ndiff()
‘+’ belongs to text1
‘-‘ belongs to text2
‘ ‘ belongs to both
```

My current set up compares the two files only. The string containing the differences between us returned

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still needing this, since there's a while you have posted.

Im working on something here and I use ndiff to compare few files from time to time. what I would do is do a grep -v [word]. On the example on the image a ndiff from nmap files will always have the Nmap 7.94... so if I dont want it to show I just do: **nmap [file1] [file2] | grep -v Nmap** and it won't show the nmap. Depends on you data format you could just do an **grep -v /** and it will probably ignore all the **/** on the comparison.
I hope I could help

[ndiff from nmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSJTW.png)